# How do I define a $_POST variable where the field name included a question mark?

Tags: php

One of the fields in my form is
Do You Have a Job Offer?

I have edited the post data into an array $form_data using this code

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $unescaped_post_data = stripslashes_deep($_POST);
} else {
  $unescaped_post_data = $_POST;
}
$form_data = json_decode($unescaped_post_data['data_json']);
```

But if I try to set a variable

```
$job_offer = $form_data->do_you_have_a_job_offer?[0];
```

Using the question mark breaks the script. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: *Why* would you use a question mark, or even a full sentence, in a control name?

Comment: Give the form field a name without a question mark?

Comment: question mark cannot be part of a identifier name in PHP.

Comment: Separate user visible text from internal variable naming! The field should be called something like `hasJobOffer` internally. What if you rephrase the user visible text to *"Do you currently have a job offer?"* because someday you decide that's better? Are you going to rename your variables? No. So don't make your variable names match your user text.

Comment: My Form name is coming via a landing page with unbounce.com so unfortunately I can't separate the visible text from the internal variable. This would have been the easiest solution!

Comment: Objects are dictionaries too. Hence all kinds of weird of charsets are allowed. The only difference to array keys is that object keys may never start with `"\0"` (old php4 hack). That weird key names should be avoided is unrelated to that PHP should be able to consume arbitrary JSON however. That being said, OP should have used `json_decode(..., TRUE)` anyway to get a boring array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use bracers:

```
$form_data->{'do_you_have_a_job_offer?'}
```

From [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Accessing elements within an object that contain characters not permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the apostrophe.

This solution works. But you should consider refactoring your code to rename the variable using standard name convention (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514895/how-do-i-define-a-post-variable-where-the-field-name-included-a-question-mark/6514919#6514919)). This will not give your results immediately, but will reduces amount of time you (or your successors) will spend debugging this code.

Comment: @Ignacio You see, in this particular case, it'll much easier to use "incorrect" (I'm still not sure why is it so) variable name. This doesn't look like some kind of "homework" application. In real world sometimes you just need to fix the problem. Renaming the variable be pain in this case, because you'll need to change html, javascript and php code. I've added your concerns into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Ivan demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514895/how-do-i-define-a-post-variable-where-the-field-name-included-a-question-mark/6514916#6514916), you can access the value without abandoning the question-mark. That being said, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

For your own sanity in the long term, the solution is to adhere to valid naming conventions. According to the documentation:

> *Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.*

Using a question mark in your labels may confuse yourself, or others, later on down the road. After all, the question mark is reserved as an operator in PHP as seen in the following ternary:

```
$foo = $bar? 0 : 1 ;
```

Avoiding it in labels will surely add many years to your life, especially if a psychotic axe-murder is hired to maintain your code later on ;)

Comment: I don't know, is an array key considered a variable?

Comment: @Jared Array keys appear to allow a great deal of flexibility, however if one of my developers were writing keys like this, I would be very nervous. In my sincere *opinion*, keys ought to enjoy the same restrictions as variables.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - I'm not disagreeing that it's *unsavory* to the prudent, organized programmers internal sense of order (because if we've been doing it long enough, we've all been there). I just don't necessarily agree that it's an invalid naming convention according to the documentation, is all.

Comment: @Jared You may be right; I'm currently trying to hunt down more information on the rules for "other labels in PHP." The rules for variables, according to the documentation, "follows the same rules as other labels in PHP." If I'm not mistaken, a key is a label as well. It's proving a bit difficult to find solid explicit on this though.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. In the interests of avoiding bloodshed we decided not to use question marks on these forms.

Comment: @Planetburgess Haha. No bloodshed here ;) I'm just really impressed that I've never seen this before; not in over 10 years. In all honesty, if it's legal (it is) and you're comfortable with it, feel free to make gratuitous use of it. Hope to see you around more often; welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think it's a great idea, Ivan Nevostruev is correct. Since he answered while I was putting the test case together, below would work:

```
<?php

class test {
    function set($key, $val) {
        $this->$key = $val;
    }
}

$form_data = new test;
$form_data->set('do_you_have_a_job_offer?',array('test'));

print_r($form_data->{"do_you_have_a_job_offer?"});

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
)
```

http://codepad.org/l62mGQ8Q